# Почему не выводятся данные из массива

Tags: java, массивы, парсер, вывод

Всем доброго дня. Делаю программу для вывода текущей погоды в консоль, и застрял на одном моменте.
Перед вами метод, который отсеивает значения температуры, влажности и тд с сайта погоды.
Сейчас мне хочется, чтобы все выводилось в столбик, вида: "Температура -3", ну и так далее.
Не могу понять, как нормально получить значения после цикла while. Внутри него все отлично выводится, однако вне него видно, что значения не заносятся корректно в массив. 
Очень прошу подсказать, что не так. Глаз замылен.

```
//Получаем чистые значения наших переменных
public static void  cleanInfOfMeteoData () throws IOException {

    //Спиок наименований полученных значений
    String[] columnNames = {"Температура ", "Ощущается, как ", "Атмосферное давление ",
            "Относительная влажность ", "Скорость ветра "};
    String[] finalMeteoData = new String[5];
    //Вытягиваем значения температуры и тд
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[-+]?[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[.]?[0-9]?");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(workWithPageElements.getInfFromPagePublic().toString());

    while (matcher.find()) {
        int i = 0;
        finalMeteoData[i] = matcher.group();
        //Выводим значения в консоль
        System.out.println(finalMeteoData[i]); //Тут все выводится нормально - зачения температуры, владности и тд
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(finalMeteoData[0]); //Тут почему то выводится самое последнее значение
    System.out.println(finalMeteoData[1]); // NULL
    System.out.println(finalMeteoData[2]); // NULL
    System.out.println(finalMeteoData[3]); // NULL
    System.out.println(finalMeteoData[4]); // NULL
}
```

Comment: `int i = 0;` вынесите перед началом цикла

Comment: Я так и знал, что проблема в какой то мелочи. Огромное спасибо, товарищ Serodv!